# Asking for an appointment

Tags: english-to-german

How can I make an appointment with doctor. Can you guide me about this translation. I would appreciate the better expressions also. I'calling....

**1:I 'm Abdullah and calling on behalf of my wife.**

*Ich bin Abdullah und rufe für meine Frau an. (Is it Ok or some better expression).

Ich bin Abdullah und rufe wegen meiner Frau an. (Is it Ok or some better expression).*

**2: It's about  my son:**

*Es geht um meinen Sohn an. Er hat Fieber. (Is it Ok)*

**3: if I know the name of doctor**

** Ich möchte gern um einen Termin mit Herrn Walter bitten.**

but if I don't know his name:

*Ich möchte gern um einen Termin mit Doktor/Arzt bitten. (Is it OK)*

Comment: German Language Stack Exchange does not endorse translation or proofreading requests. If you can narrow your question down to single issues that especially trouble you, it is on-topic for the site but as it stands it will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Sentence**

Let us be a bit nitpicky. Your first proposition is OK, but it just means you are doing it **for** her. That may be with or without her consent. As a non native English speaker, when I hear "on behalf of somebody", I tend to think of a designated representative or helper. So, if my wife had instructed me to call, I'd probably go with:

> Ich rufe im Namen meiner Frau an.

The second proposition is also correct, but it means you are calling **because** of your wife.

**Second sentence**

There is a small flaw. You should say:

> Es geht um meinen Sohn.

**Third sentence**

Not bad, but watch the articles! It should be

> Ich möchte um einen Termin mit Doktor Krueger bitten.

or

> Ich möchte um einen Termin mit dem Doktor/Arzt bitten.

In these cases "mit" implies a meeting with the doctor himself, not his assistant. I typically use the more abstract:

> Ich möchte um einen Termin bei Doktor Krueger bitten.

**Sidenotes**

Typically, the use of your first name is too personal when calling an unknown.

I personally never use "ich moechte **gern**" in requests, but that may be a personal preference.